# Meteor local server on mobile - Error: Error parsing asset manifest

Tags: meteor, heroku, meteor-mobile

I have deployed a Meteor app on Heroku.

I have added a platform: Android

When I try I build the app using the `meteor build` command `meteor build --directory ~/builds --server https://my-app.herokuapp.com` and the install the apk using `adb`, I get an error.

I get the same error when trying to run app locally, but with different server: `meteor run android-device --mobile-server https://my-app.herokuapp.com`

The error is:

```
Error: Error parsing asset manifest(…)
(anonymous function) @ webapp.js?hash=2552b0d8c8f134d5763b6897c1be6c9bfa3e9c28:68
(anonymous function) @ webapp_local_server.js:37
cordova.callbackFromNative @ cordova.js:293
processMessage @ cordova.js:1081
processMessages @ cordova.js:1104
pollOnce @ cordova.js:973
pollOnceFromOnlineEvent @ cordova.js:960
```

It looks like the problem is connected to Meteor local server which runs on mobile.

Some discussion here: https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-local-server-on-mobile-error-error-parsing-asset-manifest/21215/7

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Meteor Forum user, issue was found.

Fixed and created a pull request for the package: https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse/pull/86